# How to convert data in required json format

Tags: json, angularjs

When I get my data back through API call using angular $http service, my data looks like this,

```
 {"Modules":
     [{"ModuleId":"4b601ab6-7086-4094-a9dc-392a69cfbaa3","ModuleName":"Membership"},
      {"ModuleId":"82372172-6d82-453a-9752-39d31b795ea5","ModuleName":"Loan"},
      {"ModuleId":"3b4f4b77-c6d0-4eb5-bd6b-7aad74190783","ModuleName":"ContactUs"},
      {"ModuleId":"0ef66293-1356-46f7-b7eb-9394b9eb2e34","ModuleName":"About Us"}
      {"ModuleId":"6a2fb938-bfda-4799-8b96-a9f6c2886e29","ModuleName":"FeedBack"},  
      {"ModuleId":"a0a03589-f501-4e72-bad6-bf4743e2a4d1","ModuleName":"Fee",},
      {"ModuleId":"9ed698a6-859e-40c6-a063-e6a860b69ea5","ModuleName":"Home"}],
 "SubModules":[{"SubModuleId":"3ac796d0-4eab-4ce8-bb17-3a1a3e6a9431","ModuleId":"4b601ab6-7086-4094-a9dc-392a69cfbaa3","SubModuleName":"Get Membership",},
              {"SubModuleId":"fe4d061c-6aa3-4dbd-b5f8-460a85acbda2","ModuleId":"82372172-6d82-453a-9752-39d31b795ea5","SubModuleName":"Structure",},
              {"SubModuleId":"614107e2-b9c0-4cc3-a947-512768a910fb","ModuleId":"4b601ab6-7086-4094-a9dc-392a69cfbaa3","SubModuleName":"Our Members",},
              {"SubModuleId":"15b02cd2-46b6-481d-9480-d321c9644379","ModuleId":"82372172-6d82-453a-9752-39d31b795ea5","SubModuleName":"form"},
              {"SubModuleId":"44ea642a-99d0-4f1a-bdeb-e033ecbd3e55","ModuleId":"4b601ab6-7086-4094-a9dc-392a69cfbaa3","SubModuleName":"Inquiry"}]}
```

If you observe above data 'Modules' and 'SubModules' are connected by 'ModuleId'.

I want to convert above data into following something like this format ,

```
   ModuleName:
              Membership :
                           Get Membership
                           Our Members
                           Inquiry
                    Loan :
                           structure
                           form
               Contact Us:
               About Us  :
```

I want to get json/obj similar or relevant to shown here. I know this is not perfect at all. but i've dealt with Json so much so i even don't know how to write this. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Later, i want to create dynamic Menu using this data, using ng-repeat.

Comment: May just be a typo but you're missing a comma at the end of

:"About Us"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Does this help at all?

```
var testData = {
    "Modules": [
        {
            "ModuleId": "4b601ab6-7086-4094-a9dc-392a69cfbaa3",
            "ModuleName": "Membership"
        },
        {
            "ModuleId": "82372172-6d82-453a-9752-39d31b795ea5",
            "ModuleName": "Loan"
        },
        {
            "ModuleId": "3b4f4b77-c6d0-4eb5-bd6b-7aad74190783",
            "ModuleName": "ContactUs"
        },
        {
            "ModuleId": "0ef66293-1356-46f7-b7eb-9394b9eb2e34",
            "ModuleName": "About Us"
        },
        {
            "ModuleId": "6a2fb938-bfda-4799-8b96-a9f6c2886e29",
            "ModuleName": "FeedBack"
        },
        {
            "ModuleId": "a0a03589-f501-4e72-bad6-bf4743e2a4d1",
            "ModuleName": "Fee",

        },
        {
            "ModuleId": "9ed698a6-859e-40c6-a063-e6a860b69ea5",
            "ModuleName": "Home"
        }
    ],
    "SubModules": [
        {
            "SubModuleId": "3ac796d0-4eab-4ce8-bb17-3a1a3e6a9431",
            "ModuleId": "4b601ab6-7086-4094-a9dc-392a69cfbaa3",
            "SubModuleName": "Get Membership",

        },
        {
            "SubModuleId": "fe4d061c-6aa3-4dbd-b5f8-460a85acbda2",
            "ModuleId": "82372172-6d82-453a-9752-39d31b795ea5",
            "SubModuleName": "Structure",

        },
        {
            "SubModuleId": "614107e2-b9c0-4cc3-a947-512768a910fb",
            "ModuleId": "4b601ab6-7086-4094-a9dc-392a69cfbaa3",
            "SubModuleName": "Our Members",

        },
        {
            "SubModuleId": "15b02cd2-46b6-481d-9480-d321c9644379",
            "ModuleId": "82372172-6d82-453a-9752-39d31b795ea5",
            "SubModuleName": "form"
        },
        {
            "SubModuleId": "44ea642a-99d0-4f1a-bdeb-e033ecbd3e55",
            "ModuleId": "4b601ab6-7086-4094-a9dc-392a69cfbaa3",
            "SubModuleName": "Inquiry"
        }
    ]
};
```

Actual code:

```
var structuredData = {};

//Iterate over module data
for (var m = 0; m < testData.Modules.length; m++){
    //create key in object for each module
    structuredData[testData.Modules[m].ModuleName] = {};

    //Iterate over sub module
    for (var s = 0; s < testData.SubModules.length; s++){

        //Is sub module belonging to module
        if(testData.SubModules[s].ModuleId == testData.Modules[m].ModuleId){

            //create key in module for sub module
            structuredData[testData.Modules[m].ModuleName][testData.SubModules[s].SubModuleName] = {};
        }
    }
}

console.log(structuredData);
```

This should create an object with a nested structure like in your diagram.

http://jsfiddle.net/FQtLW/1/